# Validate showing success before validating inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form on which I am using jQuery validation to validate that the inputs are complete. However, what is happening is that validator is showing the messages but it is also making the Ajax call to boxesadd.php. I was under the impression that this ajax call was only made after a successfull validation. Why is it getting as far as the Ajax event when the inputs have not been completed. Thanks

jquery code

```
$(function () {

    $.validator.setDefaults ({

        errorClass: 'form_error',
        errorElement: 'div'
    });

    $("#BA_boxform").validate({
        rules: {
            BA_customer: {
                required: true
            },
            customerdept: {
                required: true
            },
            customeraddress: {
                required: true
            },
            BA_service: {
                required: true
            },
            BA_box: {
                required: true
            },
            BA_destdate: {
                required: true
            },
            BA_authorised: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            BA_customer: {
                required: '<br />* required: You must select a customer'
            },
            customerdept: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must select a department"
            },
            customeraddress: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must select a customer address"
            },
            BA_service: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must select a service level"
            },
            BA_box: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must enter a box number for intake"
            },
            BA_destdate: {
                required: "<br />* required: You must enter a destruction date"
            },
            BA_authorised: {
                required: "<br />* required"
            }
        }
    });

    $('#BA_boxform').on('submit', function () {

        var formdata = $('#BA_boxform').serialize() + '&submit=' + $(this).val();

        //alert(formdata);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/domain/admin/requests/boxes/boxesadd.php",
            data: formdata,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (msg) {
                //alert(msg);
                if (typeof msg.boxerrortext !== "undefined" && msg.boxerrortext == "You must enter a box for intake") {
                    $("#BA_addbox").html(msg.boxerrortext);
                } else {
                    $("#BA_addbox").html("You have successfully added box(es) " + '<span style="font-weight: bold;color:black;">' + msg.box + '</span>' + ' to the archive.' + '<br />' + 'You may now close this window or input more boxes.');
                    $("#BA_boxform").get(0).reset();
                }
                //$("#confirm_department").hide();

                /*
               var $dialog = $('<div id="dialog"></div>')
               .html('Your intake was successfully submitted and will be viewable in the reporting area.<br /><br />Thank you.');
               $dialog.dialog({
               autoOpen: true,
               modal: true,
               title: 'Box intake submission successfull',
               width: 400,
               height: 200,
               draggable: false,
               resizable: false,
               buttons: {
               Close: function() {
               $( this ).dialog( "close" );
               }
               }
               });
               */
                //alert(msg);
                //console.log(msg);
                //$("#BA_addbox").html(msg.box);

                //$("#formImage .col_1 li").show();
                //$("#BA_boxform").get(0).reset();
                //$("#boxaddform").hide();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but don't you have to call validate to see if it's valid?

Comment: @Liam I followed a youtube tutorial on setting up validate and to my understanding, valid is not compulsory but I shall look into it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

just check before you make ajax call that your messages is null.

Comment: sorry renish could you elaborate further

Comment: put one condition before ajax call, if your messages string you get null or empty then you should make ajax call otherwise not.